# Verbose logging of Java Spring Boot beans loading?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is it possible to somehow setup (preferable using YAML configuration files) a Java Spring Boot application to log in details (verbose) which beans it finds and what might cause a bean to not be loaded?

I have a Java Spring Boot 4 application that does not get to the next statement after my initially `SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args)` which means that it is stuck during initialization of the beans that it was supposed to find/lookup using annotations.

Comment: Have you actually turned up logging in your yaml config? logging.level.=TRACE

Comment: Yes. It seems to fail on a ${AppName} OS environment variable that it can't lookup even though it exists. This also means that the beans does not get loaded even though they do not use that setting.

Comment: Could you post some code and how are you setting the OS environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.beans: TRACE
```